# Moving the parent directory of a git repository that contains submodules

Tags: git

I had cloned a repository to PatchBasedInpaintingDevelop. I've been working in there for a while with no problems. Then I decided to rename the folder locally. I did 'mv PatchBasedInpaintingDevelop PatchBasedInpainting' and now git status complains about submodules, saying:

```
doriad@daviddesktop:/media/portable/Projects/PatchBasedInpainting$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository: /media/portable/Projects/PatchBasedInpaintingDevelop/.git/modules/ITKQtHelpers
```

Is there a way to do this move without breaking the submodule structure?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your **[`.gitmodules`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)** file reference the submodules using an absolute path.

Try using a *relative* path for said submodules.
(as shown, for instance, in "[Managing a set of related repositories relative in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277540/6309)")

```
submodule.<name>.path
```

> Defines the path, relative to the top-level directory of the git working tree, where the submodule is expected to be checked out.
>   The path name must not end with a `/`.
>   All submodule paths must be unique within the `.gitmodules` file.

The only other solution is to fix all the absolute paths (as in [this script](https://gist.github.com/3394771))

Comment: The only thing that seems to have the full path are submodule/.git/modules/SubModName/config , in the 'worktree' line:

./.git/modules/ITKQtHelpers/config:     worktree = /media/portable/Projects/PatchBasedInpaintingDevelop/ITKQtHelpers

Comment: I also found that SubModName/.git has a gitdir: line:

ITKQtHelpers/.git:gitdir: /media/portable/Projects/PatchBasedInpaintingDevelop/.git/modules/ITKQtHelpers

Comment: @DavidDoria how those submodules are declared in the `.gitmodules` file?

Comment: [submodule "ITKQtHelpers"]
 path = ITKQtHelpers
 url = ../ITKQtHelpers.git