# Moving a git working copy containing submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

A recent change in Git changed the way the `.git` directory is handled when using submodules.
Instead of having one `.git` per submodule, everything is now in the "root level" `.git` directory (the one corresponding to the working copy including the submodules).

Then, in each submodule, a file is created which points to the new location of the `.git` directory.

In [my project](https://github.com/roboptim/roboptim-core), I have the following `.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "tests/shared-tests"]
        path = tests/shared-tests
        url = git://github.com/roboptim/roboptim-shared-tests.git
[submodule "cmake"]
        path = cmake
        url = git://github.com/jrl-umi3218/jrl-cmakemodules.git
```

When I do `git clone --recursive`, I then obtain:

```
$ cat cmake/.git
gitdir: /home/moulard/profiles/default-x86_64-linux-ubuntu-12.04.1/src/unstable/roboptim/roboptim-core/.git/modules/cmake
```

I am currently using Git 1.8.1.5.

My questions are:

1. Why did this behavior change? I don't see any obvious gain to this new strategy.
2. How can I then move safely a working copy? (if I move my working copy, I get an error message telling me that the path to the broken gitdir is not a Git repository anymore)

Please note that this is not the same as the previous question [Moving the parent directory of a git repository that contains submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252529/moving-the-parent-directory-of-a-git-repository-that-contains-submodules) in the sense that I am *sure* this is not an issue related by the presence of an absolute path in my `.gitmodules` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.git/module` organization dates back from [git1.7.8 (December 2d, 2011)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L109-L114):

> When populating a new submodule directory with "`git submodule init`", the `$GIT_DIR` metainformation directory for submodules is created inside `$GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/` directory of the superproject and referenced via the gitfile mechanism.
>   **This is to make it possible to switch between commits in the superproject that has and does not have the submodule in the tree without re-cloning**.

However, recent bug fixes have been included in [1.8.2.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.1.txt#L51-L52) and [1.8.3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L408-L409) (April 22d, 2013):

> "git submodule update", when recursed into sub-submodules, did not acccumulate the prefix paths.

So upgrading to the very latest git release could fix this issue.

---

Here, one possible solution (with the latest git 1.8.3, April, 22d 2013), is mentioned by the [OP Thomas Moulard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442517/thomas-moulard) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160993/moving-a-git-working-copy-containing-submodules/16161950?noredirect=1#comment23103265_16161950):

> `$ git submodule deinit -f .` is working!
>   Then I can run `git submodule init` and the paths get fixed

This takes care if the (de)initialization steps (`.git/modules`)

It doesn't take care of the '`add`' step which records the url of a submodule in the `.gitmodules` file: you still need to remove it manually within that file.

Comment: actually I tried with the last release of Git and the HEAD of master but so far no luck unless there is a git command I am not aware of...

Comment: @ThomasMoulard latest being 1.8.3 in your case?

Comment: @ThomasMoulard But... but-but-but (https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes), 1.8.3 is only 15 hours old. They did 3 other releases already?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the last version. I tried 1.8.2.1 the last real release, 1.8.3 is already in `RelNotes` but there is no tag for this one yet. In either cases even the HEAD of `master` branch is not helping here (commit 118f60ee)

Comment: @ThomasMoulard o, just checking here ;) What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483276/git-submodule-not-working-after-deleting/15504813#15504813?

Comment: alas, in my case: `git rm -rf cmake` produces: `fatal: Not a git repository: /home/moulard/profiles/default-x86_64-linux-ubuntu-12.04.1/src/unstable/roboptim/roboptim-core/.git/modules/cmake` (and the directory is still here). Basically `git` is totally stuck unless I go and edit files by hand to fix paths.

Comment: @ThomasMoulard where do you do that `rm -Rf`? in `.git/module`? or in the parent repo working tree?

Comment: At the root level of the parent repo working copy. [and it is `git rm` not simple `rm`]

Comment: @ThomasMoulard in that case, I would recommend a `git submodule deinit` instead of a `git rm`. And then you add again your submodule. It is in the same spirit of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483276/git-submodule-not-working-after-deleting/15504813#15504813, but using the very latest command of git 1.8.3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309

Comment: Woosh, `$ git submodule deinit -f .` is working! Then I can run `git submodule init` and the paths get fixed. Thanks! Can you update your initial answer to incorporate `git deinit`? Then I will accept it.

Comment: @ThomasMoulard Excellent. I have included that process in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully fixed my work copy after moving it elsewhere doing the following:

- Updating the `gitdir:` path in `superproject/path/to/submodule/.git` file
- Updating the `worktree=` path in `superproject/.git/modules/path/to/submodule/config` file

I don't know why git uses absolute paths there!

(Tested on git 2.0.1.563)